# Socket.io display own socketId when page loaded (angular - factory)

Tags: angularjs, sockets, socket.io

I'm connecting to socket.io with a factory, where I have a socketId return function to give me the `socketId` of the connection so that I can display it on the website (just for testing right now).

I have my factory:

```
angular.module('testing').factory('socket', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    var socket = io.connect();

    return {
        socketId: function(){
          return socket.id;
        }
        //some more code here deleted for simplicity
    };
}]);
```

and in my controller code:

```
_this.socketId = socket.socketId();
```

Now when I open the page, `socket.socketId()` returns `undefined`, when I get it however after pressing for example a button, I get the `socketId`.

**Question:** How can I make socket.io update my variable `_this.socketId` after it got connected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'promise' ,[Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

```
return {
    socketId: function(){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var socket = io.connect();
      socket.on('connect', function() {
            deferred.resolve(socket.id); //Your socketid
        });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Rejs. It didn't worked because I cannot make another io.connect() since I would than get two separate sockets.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like socketId in the controller is initialized even before the socket could connect!

Wouldn't it be better if you would just wait for your socket to connect in the factory and broadcast the socket id once connected and you could just simply listen for it at the controller.

```
//At the factory
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on("connect",function(){
$rootscope.$broadcast("socketId",socket.id);
});

//At the controller
$scope.$on("socketId",function(data){
_this.socketId = data;
});
```

I hope this will help you, Please feel free to correct me if i'm wrong somewhere.

Comment: Saw just now your edit @TeeJay. I get this object when doing console.log(data) in the controller: ![Object](http://i.imgur.com/EdurSqt.png).

Comment: can you try passing the socket object instead of passing socket.id! I will try replicating it in my machine!